# How to change the value of an imported object in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I was trying to include an MQTT broker configuration using the ngx-mqtt plugin in ionic 3. I am using a variable for broker configuration. In my `app.module.ts` and is like this.

```
MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS = {
  hostname: '172.30.66.232',
  port: 9001,
  path: '/ws'
};
export { MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS };

export function mqttServiceFactory() {
  return new MqttService(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS);
}
```

And in my `home.ts` page, I am fetching the data from MQTT.

```
this._mqttService.observe('roomData').subscribe((message1: IMqttMessage) => {
    console.log(this.message1);  
});
```

Everything is working fine. Now I need to change exported variable `MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS` value by dynamically binding the object values from input fields.
So I'm trying to change its value in `home.ts` like this:

```
import { MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS } from '../../app/app.module'
saveBroker() {
     console.log(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS);
     export MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS = {
         hostname: this.hostname,
         port: this.port,
         path: this.protocol
     };
}
```

Here I am able to console the object properly. But not able to change its values and export it back. This is throwing me an error: `ERROR ReferenceError: MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS is not defined`

So, please suggest me how can I change the value of an object?

Comment: Hi @darshan, I wasn't able to make the ngx-mqtt plugin work in my ionic 3 app. What is the ngx-mqtt version that you used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @EsthonWood, I have used v5.4.0 in ngx-mqtt. Use this link for guidance - https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/

Answer (score 0):

You would not want to re-export back an imported object. The client and provider already shares a common MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS object. You would rather want change the content of this shared object, e.g.:

```
saveBroker() {
     console.log(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS);
     MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS.hostname = this.hostname;
     MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS.port = this.port;
     MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS.path = this.protocol;
}
```

I hope this helps for you.